# Dispatch Redux Action by Promise.all callback several API Endpoint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, promise

I must fetch from several Endpoint to get several data, then merged to single data which is will be send to reducer, then i get Promise.all, to fetch several api data then it merged, my question is, how to detect which is fail and which is success fetched?then which is success still sent to reducer, and one which fail send fail message

i work with ReactJS, Redux & Redux Thunk, when all endpoint give success callBack, all data had sent, but when one of endpoint fail, it only throw to one error which came from one of endpoint

What i've done :

```
const chartUrl = [
    requestAPI('GET', 'endpoint/a', 2).then(res => res.json()),
    requestAPI('GET', 'endpoint/b', 2).then(res => res.json()),
    requestAPI('GET', 'endpoint/c', 2).then(res => res.json()),
    requestAPI('GET', 'endpoint/d', 2).then(res => res.json()),
    requestAPI('GET', 'endpoint/e', 2).then(res => res.json()), // this endpoint fail
    requestAPI('GET', 'endpoint/f', 2).then(res => res.json()),
    requestAPI('GET', 'endpoint/g', 2).then(res => res.json())
];


let chartObj = {
        dataChart: {}
    };
Promise.all(chartUrl)
        .then(storeData => {
            let mergedData = storeData.reduce((prev, cur) => {
                prev[cur.message] = cur;
                return prev;
            }, {});
            Object.assign(chartObj.dataChart, mergedData);
            // Make detection which code=200 and success=true then dispatch to fetched_chart reducer, but when code != 200 and success=false then dispatch to fail_chart reducer
            console.log(chartObj);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            //when server has fail then dispatch to error_fetch_chart reducer
            return err;
        })
```

output :

```
http://web.data.net/api/v1/endpoint/interaction 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

i expect output like this :

```
{
  dataChart:
    {
      a: {
        code: 200,
        success: true
        data: chartA
      },
b: {
        code: 200,
        success: true
        data: chartB
      },
c: {
        code: 200,
        success: true
        data: chartC
      },
d: {
        code: 200,
        success: true
        data: chartD
      },
e: { //error callback
        message: '500 (Internal Server Error)'
    }
...
    }
}
```

Comment: Promise.all rejects if _any_ of the promises reject. My first thought would be to put a `.catch` on each of the promises so that one failure doesn't cause the whole thing to fail.

Comment: You may want [Promise.allSettled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) which is available in chrome, however can very easily be "polyfilled"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: If you want to abort in the event of a failure then you could catch and throw as [John points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57847291/dispatch-redux-action-by-promise-all-callback-several-api-endpoint/57847336#comment102121751_57847336) in the comment below.

If you catch rejections on each request, `Promise.all` won't reject when a single request fails.

```js
// util for invoking the requestAPI, capturing the path in rejection
const req = (path, arg) => requestAPI('GET', path, arg)
    .then(req.json())
    .catch(e => ({ error: e, path, arg})) 

const chartUrl = [
  req('endpoint/a', 2),
  req('endpoint/b', 2),
  // etc.
];
```

So then you can do:

```js
Promise.all(chartUrl)
  .then(results => results.map((r, index) => {
    if (r.error) {
      // deal with failed individual request
      console.error(`request for ${r.path} failed.`)
    }
    else {
      // do something with successful result
    }
  })
)
```

Comment: couldn't you just throw in the catch to bump up the chain to the promise all?

Comment: hmm. wouldn't catch and throw be the same as not catching?

Comment: Well sure assuming that each individual one doesn't need to do something else itself on a catch. (Like dispatch an error for instance).

Comment: Oh. Right. Right. I was thinking about wanting to proceed even if one request failed. If you want to abort the whole thing then sure. You could capture which one failed and throw it.

Comment: Yep, and also then each can be used individually because they have their own catch. Your solution is also good though :)

Comment: Nice Solution, but i must get what error which got, especially with code too (ex: {code:500, message: '500 (Internal Server Error)'}

Comment: All of the information provided by requestAPI will be in `error`. If you need information that isn't there then you need to fix that upstream in `requestAPI`.